# How to select a svg with title using cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

i want to click  element within div whose name is "name1", description is "description1"
and title is "title1" using cypress.

below is the dom,

```
<div data-testid="table-body" role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-0">
        <div role="cell">
            <input data-testid="table-row-checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-0-column-name">
            <button data-testid="expand-row"></button>
            <a class="subtle-link">name1</a>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-0-column-description">
            description1
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-0-column-isIcon">
            <div>
                <svg>
                    <title>title2</title>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-1">
        <div role="cell">
            <input data-testid="table-row-1-checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-1-column-name">
            <button data-testid="expand-row"></button>
            <a class="subtle-link">name1</a> //i want to click this element
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-column-description">
            description1
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-column-isIcon">
            <div>
                <svg>
                    <title>title1</title>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-2">
        <div role="cell">
            <input data-testid="table-row-checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-2-column-name">
            <button data-testid="expand-row"></button>
            <a class="subtle-link">name2</a>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-1-column-description">
            description2
        </div>
        <div data-testid="table-cell-row-0-column-isIcon">
            <div>
                <svg>
                    <title>title1</title>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As seen from above dom there is two divs with name name1 and description description1. but title is "title1", "title2"

i have tried like below,

```
cy.get('div[role="row"]')
    .find('div', 'name1')
    .contains('svg', 'title1')
    .parent()
    .click();
```

this selects the first element with name1 although title is title2

Comment: What is the exact error that are you getting. Would be great if you can add a screenshot ?

Comment: is it `cy.get` instead of `cy.getR` in your code?

Comment: @Dhamo: sorry yes its cy.get

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky, the simplest way I found is to use a filter with callback.

The `row` parameter is the raw element (not jQuery wrapped), so use `.textContent()` to get the text of the node and its descendants - [MDN - textContent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```
cy.get('div[role="row"]')                           // 3 elements found
  .filter((_, row) => {
    return row.textContent.includes('title1') &&
      row.textContent.includes('description1') &&
      row.textContent.includes('name1')             // filters to 1 element
  })
  .find('a')
  .click()
```

You can also use a selector with the filters built in

```
const selector = 'div[role="row"]' +
  ':contains("title1")' +
  ':contains("description1")' +
  ':contains("name1")';
cy.get(selector)
  .find('a')
  .click();
```

Text search within the row may be a bit imprecise, depending on if the text you are looking for appears in other columns.

A more precise filter would target the elements of each text (using jQuery here),

```
cy.get('div[role="row"]')
  .filter((_, row) => {
    const title = Cypress.$(row).find('title').text();
    const description = Cypress.$(row).find('div[data-testid="table-cell-row-column-description"]').text();
    const name = Cypress.$(row).find('a.subtle-link').text();
    return title === 'title1' &&
      description === 'description1' &&
      name === 'name1';
  })
  .find('a')
  .click()
```